# ¿Cómo filtrar y reordenar datos de una relación en Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo un modelo Owner que se relaciona con el modelo Pet y con el modelo Photo:

```
class Owner extends Model
{
    public function pets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pet');
    }

    public function photo()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Photo', 'photoable');
    }
}
```

Y a su vez, el modelo Pet también se relaciona con el modelo Photo (es decir hay una relación polimórfica):

```
class Pet extends Model
{
    public function photo()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Photo', 'photoable');
    }

}
```

Entonces en mi vista owners > show necesito mostrar todas las pets (y la photo de cada pet) del owner.

Para hacerlo, en el controlador respectivo recupero el owner y lo paso a la vista:

```
class OwnerController extends Controller
{

    public function show(Owner $owner)
    {

        $owner = Owner::findOrFail($owner->id);

        return view('admin.owners.show', compact('owner'));
    }
}
```

Y en la vista puedo acceder a las propiedades de las mascotas:

```
@foreach($owner->pets as $pet) 
{{ $pet->name }}

//Para mostrar la imagen de la mascota si es que la tiene o una imagen por defecto (no sé si hay una forma más elegante de hacer esto)
<img src="@if($pet->photo) {{ $pet->photo->url}} @else {{ '/storage/images/perro.svg' }} @endif"> 
@endforeach
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero lo que necesito es algo más específico que recuperar todas las pets y su respectiva photo. Lo que necesito es recuperar las pets en el orden que se fueron agregando y que solo se recuperen las pets que se tengan cierto estatus en un campo llamado status. Lo que se me ocurrió es hacer lo siguiente en la vista, y sí funciona:

```
@foreach($owner->pets->sortByDesc('updated_at')->where('status', '=', 'Alive') as $pet)
    {{ $pet->name }}

    <img src="@if($pet->photo) {{ $pet->photo->url}} @else {{ '/storage/images/perro.svg' }} @endif"> 
@endforeach
```

**Mi pregunta es: ¿existe una mejor manera de lograr esto, o una manera correcta o más eficiente de hacerlo?** Perdón si fui muy extenso, pero en otras preguntas que he realizado me han pedido ser más claro.

Gracias.

Comment: @BetaM Lo intenté, pero no pude hacerlo :(  edit: Ahora que recuerdo, en el modelo sí pude pero no sé si sea correcto hacerlo ahí porque en otras partes sí necesitaré recuperar todas las pets, no solo las pets cuyo status sea igual a 'Alive'.

Answer (score 1):

Consulta para obtener a todos los dueños con sus mascotas:

```
Owner::has('pets')->with(['pets' => function($query) {
    $query->whereStatus('valor')
            ->latest();
}])->findOrFail($ower->id);
```

- Cargamos al modelo `Owner` filtrando por un id en específico con todas sus relaciones definidas
- Opcionalmente si solo quieres los dueños que si tienen al menos una mascota asociada, entonces anteponemos el método `has()` con el nombre de la relación deseada como argumento
- Ahora en el método `with` como clave pasamos el nombre de la relación y como valor pasamos una función anónima donde por dentro filtramos que las mascotas vengan ordenadas de forma descendente y solo aquellas que tengan determinado status
- Para el ordenamiento descendente usamos el método `latest()` el cual de manera predeterminada usa a la propiedad `created_at`, pero en caso de no ser esta, entonces pasale como argumento el nombre de la columna usada para dicho fin

La anterior consulta no tiene por que influir o afectar el resultado que en otros métodos plantees y de esta forma sacas los filtros de la vista la cual solo esperará la data filtrada y ordenada según tus necesidades en el controlador.